# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.1

Tags: sql

I am getting an error saying that column count doesn't match value count at row 1 when I try to insert this SQL statement.

```
INSERT INTO APPLICANT (fullName, Email, CompanyName, Phone, Fax, GovernmentEmployee, Academic, InternationalAttendee, SpeakerOrPresenter, FirstTimeAttendee)

VALUES
('$fullName','$Email','$CompanyName','$Telephone','$Fax', $GovernmentEmployee, $Academic, $InternationalAttendee, $Speaker, $Presenter, $FirstTimeAttendee);
```

Comment: the number of columns don't match the number of values; it won't work. Do you want to concatenate some of the values? Do you want to insert a value or another in one of the fields? If so, what is the condition you need the values to fullfill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to insert into column : `SpeakerOrPresenter`.
Two different values : `$Speaker` and `$Presenter`.

Therefore, you have more values to insert than columns to receive the data.

You could change your query to make it look like this (where the column SpeakerOrPresenter is splitted into 2 different columns):

```
INSERT INTO APPLICANT (fullName, Email, CompanyName, Phone, Fax, GovernmentEmployee, Academic, InternationalAttendee, Speaker, Presenter, FirstTimeAttendee)
VALUES
('$fullName','$Email','$CompanyName','$Telephone','$Fax', $GovernmentEmployee, $Academic, $InternationalAttendee, $Speaker, $Presenter, $FirstTimeAttendee);
```

or like this (where the two values speaker and presenter are merged into a single one) :

```
INSERT INTO APPLICANT (fullName, Email, CompanyName, Phone, Fax, GovernmentEmployee, Academic, InternationalAttendee, SpeakerOrPresenter, FirstTimeAttendee)
VALUES
('$fullName','$Email','$CompanyName','$Telephone','$Fax', $GovernmentEmployee, $Academic, $InternationalAttendee, $SpeakerOrPresenter, $FirstTimeAttendee);
```

Comment: @user2297321 Well don't. We all make those mistakes. The more you do it the easier it will get.

Comment: Thanks, I should of posted here a few days ago. Yay for other peoples eyes.

Comment: @Bodine exactly :) Dont forget to mark this question as answered if you found out what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You have 10 columns listed in the INSERT clause and 11 values in the VALUES clause .  You must have the same number in each clause.  You have a `$Speaker` and a `$Presenter` for values, but only a `SpeakerOrPresenter` column that seems to be for both.

Comment: You are missing the Presenter field.